# Print marked 'X' 'O' in a simple Tic-Tac-Toe game made of array, loops and if-statement

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement, nested-loops

My task doesn't require me to make a full working tic-tac-toe program. I just need to be able to print the X and O onto the board.

I am at this point where I need to print 'X' and 'O' onto the board, which is the last stage.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Declare the variables
    //Create the board
        //Initialize the board with all blanks
        //Print to screen
    //Prompt user for letter 'X', 'O' or 'q' to quit
        //if the input is q, then quit.
        //if the input is X or O then select positions.
            //prompt user to choose rows & columns to mark X O positions

    //declare the variables
    char board[3][4], input; //input is for the X O q
    char selectRows, selectColumns; //these are for choosing position to mark X or O
    int rows, columns;

    //create the basic empty board
    for ( rows = 0 ; rows <3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 4 ; columns++ )
        {
            //Initialize array to blanks (' ')
            board[rows][columns] = '|';

            //print to screen
            printf( "%c   ", board[rows][columns] );
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }

    //prompt the user to input X or O
    printf( "\nHit X or O. 'q' to quit\n" );
    scanf("%c", &input);

    while ( input != 'q' )
    {
        //if the input is 'X' or 'O'
        if ( input == 'X' || input == 'O' )
        {
            //select rows
            printf("Choose 1 - 3 For Rows ");
            scanf( "\n%c", &selectRows );

            //select columns
            printf("Choose 1 - 3 For Columns ");
            scanf( "\n%c", &selectColumns );

            //Print X or O on the board
            if ( selectRows == 1 && selectColumns == 1 )

                //prompt user to hit in X or O, q to quit again
                printf( "\nHit X or O. 'q' to quit\n" );

            scanf("%c", &input);
        }

    } //end while
}//end main
```

So I was able to print the empty board and request the user to input X or O or q to quit the game.

However I don't know how to print the X and O onto the board.

How can I get the `input` which contains 'X' or 'O' to be placed in the right positions? I believe these statements should go below `if ( selectRows == 1 && selectColumns == 1 )`

If I can get `if ( selectRows == 1 && selectColumns == 1 )` right, I should be able to get it right for other `selectRows` and `selectColumns`.

Comment: Perhaps you should first create a flowchart on a paper before delving into code. Think what happens when you take user input. You will print the whole board again but with an X or O at the correct location. You dont need to handle each case of type `if ( selectRows == 1 && selectColumns == 1 )` and I dont know whether you realize it or not but once printed you cannot modify the output, you will have to reprint everything.

Comment: @sraok, see my comment to PhillipD's answer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Yeah I'm working a real assignment there. And here we all do reverse-engineering pretty much..And this only a warm-up before the real assignment begins. I guess I'll start with da flowchart first. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by sraok, it is not possible the change the output ones it was printed. You must redraw your board after every input.

Therefore, I would suggest that you define a function (e.g. `drawBoard`) that takes as input a 2d char array for example called `board[][]`. This array is initialized with spaces `" "`. 
That means all fields between your | are blank by default.

If the user wants to place a X, you can set the corresponding array element

```
board[selectRows][selectColumns] = 'X';
```

to overwrite the " " at this position with a 'X' and pass the updated `board` array to your `drawBoard` function that redraws the boards.

Remember that arrays start at 0. If you the user want to place his X in the upper left corner he would type 1 1, but the 'X' must then be placed at `board[0][0]' and so on.

Comment: And @sraok is wrong here, the characters are perfectly overwriteable once they're printed. The exact method to do that is platform-dependent, though. The most common are `ncurses` for Unix and `conio.h` for DOS.

Comment: @vines Right...I wasn't really aware of this possibility.

Comment: Uh I have no idea what are those :( Well I kinda got my answer there. Function :) Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @vines.. oh yes! I forgot about it.

Comment: @vines Can you please provide a link about do that with ncurses

Comment: @vines Is it relate to use something like `gotoxy(x,y)` and `print()` that point?